# Dns and nslookup

Tags: dns, iis, microsoft

I have an IIS server with Dns server enabled, the Iis server is connected to an AD DS and on the AD DS i have another DNS server enabled.

I have connected the DNS server on the IIS server to the DNS server on AD DS and configured forward and reverse lookup.

But from the AD DS I can't ping the domain name that is configured on the IIS DNS server but I can ping the ip address of the server...

I have checked every confirmation and restarted everything and reinstalled DNS server on IIS, still I can't get it to work...

Can someone please help me out?

Comment: When I configure DNS, I like to do them one server at a time. Think about your DNS servers as serving two roles, primary and secondary. Uninstall the secondary DNS and ignore it. Make sure the Primary DNS server is working to 100% satisfaction with all domains and all clients. Only after the Primary DNS is 100% cleanly working, install the DNS service on a secondary server. Then configure the primary to trust the secondary and transfer any zones to it. Fully test the secondary from all servers and clients. Once satisfied, add the secondary server to the network DNS configuration.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer. The issue is that the iis server is just a member of the AD DS not a domain controler since it is only serving the iis service. That's why i can't configure it to be a secoundary dns.. both are configured as primary...